# Unable to add SecuBSMPx.dll library in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working with SecuGen fingerprint libraries (SecuBSPMx.dll and SecuBSPMx.NET)
in my project,  SecuBSPMx.NET is added in assembly reference but SecuBSPMx.dll not added in Visual Studio. I have tried in many versions of Visual studio and separate laptops but error is same. Below is an error message picture is attached with this email.

[image: here is error message]

Comment: You can try to add SecuBSPMx.dll into the reference, I think that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you, but I supposed SecuBSPMx.NET depends on SecuBSPMx.dll. I had a situation almost like this recently. What worked for me, was copying the dependency dlls to /bin/debug folder where the runtime dll's are located.

This can also be achieved by placing the dll in the project folder, and setting the property "copy to output" to "copy always" or "copy if newer.

Also I had to physically remove the reference to the dll in my project and add it again